# How can I use a csv file as a parameter data source?

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

I would like to use a parameter with a csv data source. The csv would be whole numbers. I have been reading a lot but there is nothing about that. Thank you very much

So far I have made parameters with a query as a data source but this makes the parameter much slower

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can put a data source  xml or excel format
In the menu, clicking on add -> add datasource-> xml or table